# My method is returning only the last value that was gotten from the while loop

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment were we have to get characters from a file and store it in a 2D array. We're not allowed to post our code anywhere so i'll use a psuedocode. Let me know if it's not clear.

```
fillFromFile (parameters){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));//from parameter
    char[][] returnChar = new char[parm][parm];//gotten from parameters
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] spliter = null;
    int count = 0;

    while (input.hasNextLine and count < row) {
        line = input.nextLine();
        spliter = line.split(" ", 2);
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; to returncharLength; increment i) {
            for (int j = 0; to returnchar[i]Length; increment j) {
                returnChar[i][j] = spliter[0].charAt(j);
            }
        }   
    }
    return returnChar;
}
```

If I print out from the method directly, the correct values are shown but we can't print from methods. There's a toString() method to handle that already.

The 2D array being returned are just the last characters.
e.g, if this is the expected value,

```
r e
r e
o p
b n
```

this is what is being returned

```
b n
b n
b n
b n
```

I've tried doing a deep copy, before and after returning it but there's no difference. My deep copy method looks like this :

```
private static char[][] deepCopy (char [][] data){
    char [][] newArray = new char [//][//];
    for (int i = 0; i < length i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
            newArray[i][j] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

I think the while loop is overwriting all the data before exiting. How can I fix this ?

If something is not clear, please let me know and i'll edit my question.

I've also tried returning the 2d array at different parts of the method

This is an example of how I'm using the returned 2d array

variableX = new ClassName (2dArrayThatWasReturned);
   return variableX;

-> variableX is of type ClassName and the constructor accepts a 2d array
-> The 2D array that was passed will have it values assigned to an instance 2d array. The instance 2d array is the one that gets printed

Comment: how is the array being created? how are the characters being stored? are you allowed to ask anywhere?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I've edited my question

Comment: reading one line, filling the **whole** array (not only one *line*), with that data; repeat for next next - the first `for` loop (over `i`) is *too much*

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger could you explain more?

Comment: you are filling the WHOLE array, that is, all rows with each line you read, overwriting previous read values.

Comment: row is supposed to be filled. That's why i'm going from 0 to row.  @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: Kindly update your answer to show how the line is read?

Comment: @Ravik I've updated it

Comment: but all rows with the same data? try to figure out what happens when reading the last line

Comment: how would you suggest I fix it then? I've been stuck since the past 4 days. And also, if I add a println inside the for loop, the values that are printed are correct (but multiples of it). @CarlosHeuberger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your loop:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; to returncharLength; increment i) {
>     for (int j = 0; to returnchar[i]Length; increment j) {
>        returnChar[i][j] = spliter[0].charAt(j);
>     }
> }
> ```

will override the whole array because you go from row `0` to `returnchar.length`, every time. Instead you need to fill only the next row after the last one. You can rewrite your `for` loops as follow:

```
for (int r=0; r<returnchar.length; r++) { // "r" for row
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] splitter = line.split(" ", 2);
    for (int c=0; c<returnchar[r].length; c++) { // "c" for column
        returnchar[r][c] = splitter[c];
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make some adjustments but your answer helped me, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is how to print a pretty Array 2D :

```
for (char[] x : returnChar) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
}
```